# Using ng-controller twice on dom elements in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, controller

I have to use same controller on two dom elements. I learned that using ng-controller on two elements will instantiate two instances. I have to share a variable between those two instances. So what I did is I created  a service and assigned watch in my controller to observe that variable present in my service.

But I don't see the second controller getting updated.

Below is the jsfiddle link I tried to get it to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/jnj6y/251/

JS code:

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);
myModule.controller('mainCtrler',function($scope){
              // $scope.dummy="main" 
                });
myModule.controller('SFCtrler',function($scope,highlightService) {
$scope.dummy="hi";
 $scope.submit = function(){
     highlightService.setDummy("howdy");
        $scope.dummy=highlightService.getDummy();
    };
$scope.$watch(function () {highlightService.getDummy(); },function(newVal, oldVal) { 
        alert(highlightService.getDummy());
        $scope.dummy=highlightService.getDummy();   
        },
        true);  
    });
myModule.service('highlightService', function() {
var dummy ='default';
var setDummy = function(input){
    dummy = input;
}
var getDummy = function(){
    return dummy;
}
 return {       
      setDummy: setDummy,
      getDummy: getDummy    
};
});
```

HTML code:

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrler">
<div ng-controller="SFCtrler" > 
     <p>{{dummy}}</p>
            <form id='sf' ng-submit="submit();" >
                <input ng-model="SearchTerm" placeholder="Search current record"  type="text" >
            </form>
        </div>   
<div ng-controller="SFCtrler" > 
<p>{{dummy}}</p>                
        </div>   
</div>
```

Can you guys point what I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`function () {highlightService.getDummy(); }` should be:

```
function() {
  return highlightService.getDummy();
}
```

It needs to return a value to `$scope.$watch`.

Full updated watcher code:

```
$scope.$watch(function () {

  return highlightService.getDummy();

}, function(newVal, oldVal) { 

  $scope.dummy = newVal;  

}, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. It works now. :) Is this the best way to use same controller on two dom elements. Or is there any better alternate approach

Comment: @javaMan, a controller should only exist for one component. Services are for sharing functionality. You are doing it correctly (according to what Angular preaches).

Comment: Thanks for confirming

Answer (score 1):

I've updated your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zwa3s77c/
You don't want to have a primitive variables as a scope variables.

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);
myModule.controller('mainCtrler',function($scope){
});

myModule.controller('SFCtrler',function($scope,highlightService) {
    $scope.dummy={val: "hi"};
    $scope.submit = function(){
        highlightService.setDummy("howdy");
        $scope.dummy=highlightService.getDummy();
    };

    $scope.$watch(function () {
        highlightService.getDummy();
        }, function(newVal, oldVal) { 
            alert(highlightService.getDummy().val);
            $scope.dummy=highlightService.getDummy();   
        }, true);  
});
myModule.service('highlightService', function() {
    var dummy ={val:'default'};
    var setDummy = function(input){
        dummy.val = input;
    }
    var getDummy = function(){
        return dummy;
    }
     return {       
          setDummy: setDummy,
          getDummy: getDummy    
    };
});
```

Here' more for reference:
http://www.codelord.net/2014/05/10/understanding-angulars-magic-dont-bind-to-primitives/

Comment: This explains alot. because Some where in my code I am not using primitives and that code works fine. Never realized that primitives can be so dangerous. Thanks for the explanation